# Regression: Test data for prediction requires class value? in Weka

Tags: python, weka

M5P tree model from weka.classifiers: python-weka-wrapper 
Each row in my arff file consists of 6 attributes with 6th attribute being the target variable for which the model is being trained.
I am using weka.core.converters.ArffLoader to the arff file to train. 
After the training, if i want to make predictions with some test data, I am creating instances and passing it to the built model to predict. In the instances i am passing only the values of the 5 attributes and not the target variable's value. I am getting a java exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Sethuraman/PycharmProjects/Test_printer/m_M5P.py", line 85, in 
>       pred_dict1[index + 1] = cls.classify_instance(instance)
>     File "C:\Users\Sethuraman\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\python_weka_wrapper-0.3.8-py2.7.egg\weka\classifiers.py", line 105, in classify_instance
>       return self.__classify(inst.jobject)
>     File "C:\Users\Sethuraman\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\javabridge-1.0.14-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\javabridge\jutil.py", line 852, in fn
>       raise JavaException(x)
>   javabridge.jutil.JavaException: Src and Dest differ in # of attributes: 5 != 6

why should I provide the target variable value? Is it necessary to pass the target value also? Essentially after the training the model should predict the target value. If yes, why? If no, how to deal with it?
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Add](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Add.html) filter to introduce a new attribute. By default, this filter will mark all values of the new attribute as missing ("?"). Just make sure that the name of this new attribute and, in case of nominal class, the order of class labels is exactly the same as in the training data.

Comment: The link that you have provided for Add filter is for implementation in Java. Can you please tell me how to implement this in py-weka? cite some example? I am using [this example](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/blob/master/src/wekaexamples/core/dataset.py) for creating attributes and instances, but for a numeric attribute, how to add '?' on the go?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *validation*, you should definitely provide target values; how does the algorithm know how well it's done otherwise?  But if you just want it to predict on that set, it seems the best way is to fill the target spot with '?', so that the data still has the 6 attributes, with the target simply marked as unknown. See http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions for more.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have edited my question. I do not want to validate the model. Just make predictions on test data. I am using `python weka wrapper` and creating instances by using the data read separately from .csv files. Since I don't have the target value information, what should I do?

Comment: see the edited answer. The documentation seems to suggest the only way to make this work is with marking the target attribute unknown for each data point.

Comment: Please bear with me if i sound silly. I am trying to create the instance in python, so if I have to add the 6th attribute, it needs to be added as string '?' at the end of the instance list. While trying to predict, the wrapper is throwing a Value error saying it is not able to convert the string to float; which is understandable because my target variable is float. Am I missing something here? how to deal with this?

Comment: what I mean is for the .csv/.arff file to have the '?', so that that attribute is marked as unknown.  Not having used py-weka myself (although I've used weka and python separately) I don't know if there is some other way to mark the attribute as unknown as in just before processing.